# how to add google chrome specific css which should override generic css?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

> First two lines are generic css which is interpreted by all browsers
>   & next 2 lines are chrome specific. But when i run the page chrome
>   does not override its specific css. It just interprets generic.

```
       th.column_cars  { width:71.2%; }


                            td.column_cars { width:71.5%; }


                            .chrome th.column_cars { width:72.6%; }


                            .chrome td.column_cars { width:72.6%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query for this. Write like this:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
 .chrome td.column_cars { width:72.6%; }

}
```

There is no CSS for only Chrome but for webkit base browsers.

Comment: hey @sandeep this solution dont work...it says Unexpected symbol "and"

Comment: may be there is some problem in your code check these links http://www.benjaminoakes.com/2011/01/28/webkit-specific-css-rules-or-hacks-if-you-prefer/  http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/browser-specific_css_hacks/